# Fluent NHibernate & Migrator problem with CRUD operations

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent

I have a problem with CRUD operations in three classes

My classes:

```
public class A 
{
 public virtual int Id { gry; set;} 
 public virtual string Text { gry; set;} 
 public virtual IList<B> Bs { gry; set;} 
}    

public class B 
{
 public virtual int Id { gry; set;} 
 public virtual string Text { gry; set;} 
 public virtual A A { get; set; }
 public virtual C C { gry; set; } 
}
```

And

```
public class C
{
 public virtual int Id { gry; set; } 
 public virtual string Something { gry; set; } 
}
```

I use Fluent NHibernate and Fluent Migrator.

I have a problem with the correct configuration of these tools.  When I want to save a new object to the database, I have to perform Save operations in the appropriate order - first on objects C, then place them in objects of class B and only then add the created elements to the list of variables in class A and I save them.

I would just like to save the object of class A to the database and from the slot machine of his children.  I also have the same problem when deleting from the database. 
I created my own HasManyConvention class with AllDeleteOrphan cascade and it didn't help. I added to the patch creating a table B in the database in Fluent Migrator with Rule.Cascade on FKs and in case of deleting directly objects of class A, B are also deleted from the database, but C are already left.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation properties are not unequivocally describing the relationships between objects. I think it's even impossible to save C based on current navigation properties, which cannot be used to define fluent mapping. You could add property B in class C and then try the following:

I'm assuming you have OneToMany between A and B (many Bs pointing to one A), and OneToOne between B and C (one C pointing to one B).

'A' mapping:

```
  HasMany(x => x.Bs).Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

'B' mapping:

```
  References(x => x.A);
  HasOne(x => x.C).Cascade().All();
```

'C' mapping:

```
    //nothing
```